# how to find $(I + uv^T)^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^N, v^Tu \neq -1$. Then I know that $I +uv^T \in \mathbb{R}^{N \times N}$ is invertible and I can verify that $$(I + uv^T)^{-1} = I - \frac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}.$$ But I am not able to derive that inverse on my own. How to find it actually? That is if am given $A =  I +uv^T$ and I am asked to find $A^{-1}$, how to get the answer?

Comment: What? First, in different words, you say you know what the inverse is. Then  you don't know it? And you should be requiring $v^Tu\neq -1$. It's obvious and irrelevant that $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^N, u^Tv \neq -1$.

Comment: @GItGud OP says they can verify it but doesn't know how they would come up it on their own. This type of "how would we actually get this expression" is ubiquitous; surely *anybody* who does math has had the same type of question multiple times before.

Comment: @whacka I reread the question and I really can't interpret it that way, but OK.

Comment: "I know that it's invertible, I can verify the formula for the inverse, but I don't know how to derive it on my own" - I don't see how it could be any more clear, especially since this is a universal experience we've all had before, including you surely.

Comment: @whacka Here's how to make it more clear: "I don't know how could I have derived it such an identity from scratch".

Comment: Seems superfluous, but OK.

Comment: @whacka How is it superfluous? Not only it's not superfluous, as it stands the question doesn't ask what he wants to ask. He's using the present tense ("not able to derive it on my own"). But he is able to do it.

Comment: @GitGud The present tense is correct, OP doesn't know how to derive it. Why do you claim he is "able to do it"? Do you understand the difference between "verify" and "derive" in this context? Even if you claim not to understand, so as to never admit a failure, you should have been able to determine OP's meaning easily and without aid, because as I said this experience is *universal* - even you have had this experience.

Comment: @whacka There is no difference. A verification is a derivation.

Comment: And there's your problem.

Comment: @whacka Yours, actually.

Comment: @GitGud I have replied [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16420/discussion-between-whacka-and-git-gud) so as to not further exacerbate this already-unreasonably-large discussion.

Comment: For $u, v$ with small norm, we can utilize *Neumann series* to expand the inverse in terms of power series. That yields the desired formula for small $u, v$. Now you can either argue in the opposite direction by claiming and verifying that this formula continues to hold for the other cases, or appeal to the analytic continuation argument.

Comment: @sos440 Heh, you're a very analytic-minded person aren't you? :-) Since I presume the identity holds with any base field, we should be able to appreciate both a purely algebraic argument at the heart, and this other approach to show off the power of analysis.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Insightful proofs for Sherman-Morrison Formula and Matrix Determinant Lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252367/insightful-proofs-for-sherman-morrison-formula-and-matrix-determinant-lemma)

Answer (score 3):

If you are just looking for a way to come up with a guess, you could try starting with $(1+u^Tv)^{-1} = 1 - u^Tv + (u^Tv)^2 + \cdots = 1 - (u^Tv - (u^Tv)^2 + (u^Tv)^3 - \cdots)$. We could factor a $u^Tv$ on the left of the bracketed term, or the right, but that will not give anything useful: instead take a $u^T$ out on the left and a $v$ on the right to get

$$1 - u(1-v^Tu + (v^Tu)^2 - \cdots)v^T $$
which for small $v^Tu$ is
$$ 1 - \frac{uv^T}{1+v^Tu}$$

These manipulations are not legitimate in general, but they do at least suggest that this might be the correct answer, and you can then check that it really is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you guess that the inverse has a similar form,
$$(I+uv^T)^{-1}=\alpha I+\beta uv^T\ ,$$
then multiplying out and equating coefficients will solve the problem.

Comment: can u please explain the intuition behind the guess?

Comment: Not really, it just seems to me a reasonable possibility which might very well not work.  But turns out it does work.  I guess also it helped that I was familiar with the fact that $uv^Tuv^T$ is a scalar times $uv^T$.

Comment: The intuition is the following any vector orthogonal to $v$ ($u$)will be an left (right) eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. The similar relation must hold for the inverse matrix.

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as Matthew's answer, but written the right way around.

Recall the geometric series:

$$ 1+q+q^2 + q^3 + … =\sum_{k=0}^∞ q^k =  \frac{1}{1-q}\qquad\text{for $|q|<1$}$$

This series works the same way for square matrices, but is then often called [Neumann Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) instead.

$$  + A + A^2 + A^3 + … = \sum_{k=0}^∞ A^k =  (-A)^{-1}\qquad\text{for $ρ(A)<1$}
$$

Here $ρ(A) = \max\{|λ|∣ \text{λ is an eigenvalue of $A$}\}$ is the [spectral radius](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_radius) of $A$. Note that $ρ(A)<‖A‖$ for any induced matrix norm.

**That's basically it.**

---

Now, let's apply this formula to $+uv^⊤$, assuming $‖uv^⊤‖<1$. Note that

$$(-uv^⊤)^k = -(uv^⊤)(uv^⊤)…(uv^⊤) = -u(v^⊤u)(v^⊤u)…(v^⊤u)v^⊤ = -(-v^⊤u)^{k-1}uv^⊤$$

Thus

$$(+uv^⊤)^{-1} = ∑_{k=0}^{∞} (-uv^⊤)^k =   - \Big( ∑_{k=1}^{∞} (-v^⊤u)^{k-1}\Big)uv^⊤  =  - \frac{uv^⊤}{1-v^⊤u}$$

Note that the last step works because $‖uv^⊤‖ <1 ⟹ |v^⊤ u| <1$. After the inverse is found in this case it is easy to check that the formula works, even when $‖u^⊤v‖≥1$, except of course when $v^⊤u = -1$, in which case $+uv^⊤$ is not invertible.

In the case where you have $A+uv^⊤$ with $A$ invertible, you simply apply the formula on

$$ (A+uv^⊤)^{-1} = \Big(A(+A^{-1}uv^⊤)\Big)^{-1} = (+A^{-1}uv^⊤)^{-1}A^{-1}$$