# Show that $(A+BC^{T})^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}B\left(I+C^{T}A^{-1}B\right)^{-1}C^{T}A^{-1}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Suppose $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is invertible, $B,C\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times m}$ and $\left(I+C^{T}A^{-1}B\right)^{-1}$ exists. Show that
>   $$
> \begin{equation}
> (A+BC^{T})^{-1}=A^{-1}-A^{-1}B\left(I+C^{T}A^{-1}B\right)^{-1}C^{T}A^{-1}
> \end{equation}
> $$

I am having a lot of trouble with what appears to be simple algebraic manipulation. I have tried to approach this problem in many different ways (too many to write out), but here is the approach I used that seems to have got me the "furthest":

$$
\begin{align}
A^{-1} &= \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}\left(A+BC^{T}\right)A^{-1} \\
&= \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}\left(I + BC^{T}A^{-1}\right) \\
&= \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1} + \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}BC^{T}A^{-1} \\
\\
A^{-1} - \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}&= \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}BC^{T}A \\
\left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}&=A^{-1} - \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}BC^{T}A^{-1} \\
&= A^{-1}-A^{-1}A\left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}BC^{T}A^{-1} \\
&= A^{-1} - A^{-1}\left[\left(A+BC^{T}\right)A^{-1}\right]^{-1}BC^{T}A^{-1} \\
&= A^{-1}-A^{-1}\left(I+BC^{T}A^{-1}\right)^{-1}BC^{T}A^{-1}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: What do you get when you make the product $$\big( A+BC^t \big) \big( A^{-1}-A^{-1}B(I+C^tA^{-1}B)^{-1}C^tA^{-1} \big)$$ ? If its the identity matrix, necessarily $$\big( A+BC^t \big)^{-1} = \big( A^{-1}-A^{-1}B(I+C^tA^{-1}B)^{-1}C^tA^{-1} \big)$$

Comment: When you wrote $A^{-1} = \left(A+BC^{T}\right)^{-1}\left(A+BC^{T}\right)A^{-1}$, you needed first to verify the invertibility of $\left(A+BC^{T}\right)$.

Comment: @Azif00 Thank you, yes I have been able to do this and show that the product is indeed equal to the identity, but how can I derive the result directly (ie. starting from $(A+BC^{T})^{-1}$ (and assuming that it is invertible)?

Comment: [Woodbury identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity).

Comment: @Andrew If you'd like to derive the result directly, I suggest following the [blockwise elimination proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity#Derivation_via_blockwise_elimination) given on wikipedia

Comment: @Andrew the proof can be framed similarly to [how I prove the Sherman Morrison formula here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3069206/81360)