# How do you understand matrices under a fraction?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

I was trying to understand the derivation of the Sherman-Morrison formula when I saw [this question/answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252367/insightful-proofs-for-sherman-morrison-formula-and-matrix-determinant-lemma) and the formula

$
(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1}-\frac{A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}}{1+v^TA^{-1}u}
$

It's my understanding that you cannot divide matrices.  Instead you have to multiply by the inverse.  So how do you interpret the right hand side of the equation?  When rewriting the equation where do you put the denominator?  You could write it as

$
(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1}-(1+v^TA^{-1}u)^{-1} \ * \ A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1}
$

or

$
(A+uv^T)^{-1} = A^{-1}- A^{-1}uv^TA^{-1} \ * \ (1+v^TA^{-1}u)^{-1}
$

which I assume would result in a different answer because matrix multiplication is not commutative.  Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: The denominator is a scalar, not a matrix.

Comment: Oh, interesting.  How do you know that?

Comment: Multiplying a $1\times n$ vector by a $n\times n$ matrix and then by a $n\times 1$ vector leaves you with a single number, by definition of matrix multiplication. So $v^TA^{-1}u$ is just a scalar.

Comment: $A^{-1}u$ is a vector, so $v^T A^{-1}u$ is the dot product of vectors, which is a scalar. Also note: there is a version of this where it is a matrix, called the Woodbury formula